# Django Rest change primarykey in URL to use custom key

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

i have two models Stats and Autor, how i can change primary key to use a unqiue field search by parameter(Subname in Autor model) i thinking about APIView but anyone can show me how use this?
example : http://127.0.0.1:8000/autors/Subname

models.py

```
class Stats(models.Model):

# Fields
Word = models.CharField(name='Word',max_length=255)
Word_count = models.IntegerField(name="Count")

def __str__(self):
    return self.Word+":"+str(self.Count)

class Autor(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
sub_name = models.CharField(name='Subname', max_length=255, default='puste')
# Relationship Fields
words = models.ManyToManyField(Stats)
```

serializers.py

```
class StatsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model=Stats
    fields=('Word','Count')

class AutorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
words=StatsSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)
class Meta:
    model=Autor
    fields=('name','words')
```

Views.py

```
class AutorView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Autor.objects.all()
serializer_class = AutorSerializer

class StatsView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StatsSerializer
    queryset = Stats.objects.all()
```

Urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from Teonite import views
from rest_framework import routers

router=routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('autors',views.AutorView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include(router.urls))
]
```

I using django 2.0, python 3.6 and Django REST framework 3.8.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, make `sub_name` field to `unique` as,

```
class Autor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_name = models.CharField(name='Subname', max_length=255, default='puste',unique=True)
    # Relationship Fields
    words = models.ManyToManyField(Stats)
```

Then, change lookup-field attribute in your view as,

```
class AutorView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Autor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AutorSerializer
    lookup_field = sub_name
```

If you didn't change to unique field in models, it may cause error, because the `Detail API` retrives only `One` instance with respect to the `lookup-field`